# Convert hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00 to Date YYYYMMDDHH in C programming

Tags: c, date, datetime, netcdf

I have obtained a date from a netcdf file in the format of hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00.  I need to convert this date into the format YYYYMMDDHH where Y is year, M is month, D is day and H is hour in a c program.  Any idea on how to do this?

I know in python I was able to do this by the following lines of code:

```
dttme=datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(hours=dates[0])
dttme2=datetime.strftime(dttme, "%Y%m%d%H")
```

but how do I do this in C programming?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is your research effort, be it right or wrong?

Comment: you need to use scanf or fscanf

Comment: Did you try a google search first? How it did not help you?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - spamming nasty comments is not helpful

Comment: @Hogan Sorry, I did not mean to be rude. I was just being sure OP did the background work already. Also, I'm not very sure of _spamming_, anyways. No offence. :)

Comment: google search was to no avail.  How do I use scanf?

Comment: @jms1980 Maybe once reading [ask] will help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `scanf`, you can use `strptime`.
Have a look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html

At the bottom of the page there is also an example of using `strptime` and `strftime`.

Comment: It should be noted that `strptime` is a POSIX function as opposed to part of the c-standard. It has been included in the c-library since libc 4.6.8 and will require_XOPEN_SOURCE or _GNU_SOURCE defined for use with glibc2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mktime()` ability to cope with values outside its primary range.

Use `"%Y%m%d%H"` for `YYYYMMDDHH` format

```
char *t2000(char * dest, size_t size, int hours) {
  // zero all fields
  struct tm tm = {0};
  tm.tm_year = 2000 - 1900;
  // tm.tm_mon = 1-1;
  tm.tm_mday = 1;
  tm.tm_hour += hours;
  if (mktime(&tm) == -1) return NULL;
  if (strftime(dest, size, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm) == 0) return NULL;
  return dest;
}
```

Comment: @David C. Rankin Coding mistakes corrected.  `hours` range good for at least years 1902 - 2037 with my gcc.

Comment: The only thing that gave me pause was sticking the current hours-since-epoch in and I got 2045 as the year out. I may have messed something up.

Comment: @David C. Rankin True that the extended range in which `mktime()` works is not defined - YMMV I have had no trouble with values in the decades about 2000.

Comment: A favorite link describing the *"mess"* [**Time, Clock, and Calendar Programming In C**](http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find it with google search -- I searched for scanf, this page was first: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Here is an example:

```
 scanf("%4i-%2i-%2i %2i:%2i:%2i",&year,&month,&day,&hour,&min,&sec);
```

where all of those are declared as integers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that a `netcdf` file provides you with only the *hours-since-epoch* and you need to convert the number of hours to a date string, then unless you supplement the current hours since epoch with current minutes and seconds past the hour, your string will be limited to displaying a date string that is only accurate to the hour (no min or sec). Realistically, that is all you have, hours-data, no minutes or seconds, if I understand you correctly.

Taking that into account, you can use the hours with `localtime` to obtain a broken-down time struct to use with `strftime` to obtain a date string accurate to the hour with something similar to:

```
char *epoch_h2date (char * dest, size_t size, int hours)
{
    struct tm *tm = NULL;
    time_t t = hours * 3600;    /* seconds since epoch  */

    tm = localtime (&t);

    if (strftime(dest, size, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm) == 0)
        return NULL;

    return dest;
}
```

If all you have is *hours-since-epoch* and you want to provide minutes/seconds data, then you are essentially just inventing that data. That being said, you can easily take the current seconds-since-epoch and take the current minutes:seconds past the hour from that.

Comment: `time_t t = hours * 3600;` relies on `time_t` being in seconds - something not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Hmm... here it really relies on `hours` being in hours and `time_t` being equivalent to `int` (which according to the mess of documentation is a reasonably standard implementation). As for the `localtime` call, it is in seconds -- (or at least 3600 times the hours `:)`